# Elasticsearch query issue with reserved characters

Tags: elasticsearch

I have indexed two documents

1) `{"title": "+" }`

2)`{"title": "a + b" }`

By using query string query , I have search queries for the above two documents in different manner.
Also, I have not changed any analyzers. Default analyzer has been used.

1.

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "title",
      "query": "+"
    }
  }
}
```

the above query gives a parsing exception which is legit.

2.

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "title",
      "query": "\\+"
    }
  }
}
```

this query outputs:

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "my_index1",
    "_type": "my_item",
    "_id": "005",
    "_score": 0.9808292,
    "_source": {
      "title": "+"
    }
  }
]
```

the above output also seems legit.

3.

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "title",
      "query": " + "
    }
  }
}
```

in the above query space exists before and after "+" character , this outputs:

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "my_index1",
    "_type": "my_item",
    "_id": "005",
    "_score": 1.2039728,
    "_source": {
      "title": "+"
    }
  }
]
```

My issue is why parsing exception is not thrown here and why escaping "+" is not necessary here"? If Elasticsearch is finding a way to parse "+"in some manner, why is "a + b" not in the hits?

4.

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "title",
      "query": "a + b"
    }
  }
}
```

this query outputs:

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "my_index1",
    "_type": "my_item",
    "_id": "005",
    "_score": 0.9808292,
    "_source": {
      "title": "+"
    }
  }
]
```

I don't understand how my query is parsing "+" and not throwing an exception. If Elasticsearch is finding a way to parse "+"in some manner, why is "a + b" not in the hits?
5.

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "title",
      "query": "a \\+ b"
    }
  }
}
```

output to this query :

```
"max_score": 0.6931472,
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "my_index1",
    "_type": "my_item",
    "_id": "007",
    "_score": 0.6931472,
    "_source": {
      "title": "a + b"
    }
  }
]
```

if the query is using default analyzers (since I have not used any analyzers) how is "+" not in the hits here?

Comment: which version of ES are you using? Also, shouldn't the plus char be escaped like "query": "\\+"

Comment: @lolotron I am using elasticsearch 6.3.2. Yes, "+" char is been escaped using "\\+". It was a typo mistake.

Comment: what is the type of field title? keyword or text? It must be keyword based on your examples. Can you confirm that

Comment: I have not put  a mapping file, hence it would take the default type.

Comment: can you run `GET /my_index1/my_item/_mapping` and see what is the type for _title_ field?

Comment: "term": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "title": {
                                        "type": "text",
                                        "fields": {
                                            "keyword": {
                                                "type": "keyword",
                                                "ignore_above": 256
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                    }